# React-Redux: Obtain details when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning to use react and redux and I'm making a little bit of confusing..

What I Would to do:

- Recover data from api and create a list with a button (done)
- Click on button and recover information (this is the problem, I would to do this in another page, but at the moment is ok also in the same page)

*reducers.js*

```
const initialState = {
    meetings: [],
    idmeeting: []
}

export const reducer = (state = [] , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'MEETINGS_LIST':
            return [...state, ...action.meetings];
        case 'MEETING_CURRENT':
            return [...action.idmeeting]
        default: 
            return state;
    }

}

export default reducer;
```

*actions.js*

```
export const meetingsList = (meetings) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, {
            headers : { 
                'Accept': 'application/json'
               }
        })
        .then(
            res => res.json(),
            error => console.log('An error occurred.', error))
        .then(meetings => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'MEETINGS_LIST',
                meetings: meetings
            })
        })
    }
}

export const meetingSingle = (idmeeting) => {
 // at the moment I use the information from the user 1
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`, {
        headers : { 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
           }
    })
    .then(
        res => res.json(),
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error))
    .then(idmeeting => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'MEETING_CURRENT',
            idmeeting: idmeeting
        })
    })
}
```

*MeetingList.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { meetingsList, meetingSingle } from '../Redux/actions';

class MeetingsList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.meetingsList();
}

handleClick(id){
    alert("ALERT " + id);
}


render(){
    console.log(this.props.meetings)
    const listMeetings = this.props.meetings.map((meeting) => 
    <li key={meeting.id}>{meeting.name}
    <button key={meeting.id} onClick={meetingSingle(meeting.id)} value={meeting.id}>{'Details'}</button>
    </li>);
    return(
        <div>
                   <ul>{listMeetings}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {meetings: state}
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        meetingsList: (meetings) => dispatch(meetingsList(meetings)),
        meetingSingle: (idmeeting) => dispatch(meetingSingle(idmeeting))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MeetingsList)
```

So my problem is to click on button and do an api call to receive the details. Can anyone help me to understand where is the problem (at the moment I receive the error that dispatch is not defined in actions, but I don't think that this is the only problem )

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your action will dispatch when component will render with wrong data. You need to provide a function to onClick instead of executing inside onClick

This

```
onClick={meetingSingle(meeting.id)}
```

Should be

```
onClick={() => meetingSingle(meeting.id)}
```

You need to import store in actions.js file and then use `store.dispatch()` where needed

```js
import { store } from './your path for store';

export const meetingSingle = (idmeeting) => {
 // at the moment I use the information from the user 1
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`, {
        headers : { 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
           }
    })
    .then(
        res => res.json(),
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error))
    .then(idmeeting => {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'MEETING_CURRENT',
            idmeeting: idmeeting
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so I should create a function meetingSingle? But the error: 
`'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef` in actions.js persist

Comment: @Zohaibljaz Ok this error is fixed (but why for the other action I haven't use it?? ). Anyway now said `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: action.idmeeting is not iterable` in reducers.js when I click on the button.

Comment: because you are doing this in reducer `[...action.idmeeting]`? this seems wrong logic and breaking as well since you can use `...` with number

Comment: You are right, I can use only `action.idmeeting` and it recover the element from the api call. But it gives me error in `this.props.meetings.map is not a function`. I'm a little bit confused

Comment: what do you want when you will click in certain meeting button. ?

Comment: the information that I recover from the api call users/1 and it works but it gives me also this error. My final goal will be that depending on the button clicked and then retrieved the ID to make an API call with the information for the meeting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211225/discussion-between-zohaib-ijaz-and-jack23).